# Saving values into List in a class by using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Item with a string List ImagesUrl property:

```
public class Item
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<string> ImagesUrl { get; set; }
    ..
}
```

And I want to parse a XML file and save each node item into var items. In node item there are nodes img1, .. , img5 and right these I want to save into the Img property by using LINQ command like this:

```
var items = from item in xmlDocument.Descendants("item")
                select new Item
                {
                    Name = item.Element("name").Value,
                    ImagesUrl = item.Element("img1").Value, //....?
                    ..
                };
```

How you can see, I don't know how I could save the img1..5 values in LINQ. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var items = from item in xmlDocument.Descendants("item")
            select new Item
            {
                Name = item.Element("name").Value,
                ImagesUrl = Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(x => item.Element("img"+x).Value).ToList();
            };
```

Code is self-explanatory here.

Answer (score 2):

Universal solution independent on count of imgX elements

```
            var items = from item in Xml.Descendants("item")
                        select new Item
                        {
                            Name = item.Element("name").Value,
                            ImagesUrl = item.Elements()
                                            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("img"))
                                            .Select(e => e.Value)
                                            .ToList()
            };
```